# Formatar data em Java web com Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Fala galera, preciso formatar uma data em Java.

Estou utilizando Java web, Primefaces, MVC, TDD, JSF, Hibernate. Sou estagiário e estou fazendo um projeto de Gerenciador de Projetos para minha empresa.

Minha view de entrada de data está assim:

```xml
<h:outputText value="Data de Início"/>
    <p:calendar  value="#{projetoBean.projetoCadastro.dataInicio}"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
    </p:calendar>
```

Minha view para mostrar a data está assim:

```xml
        <p:column headerText="Data de Início" filterBy="#{projeto.dataInicio}">
    <h:outputText value="#{projeto.dataInicio}"/>
    </p:column>
```

A entidade assim:

```java
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "dataInicio_projeto")
private Date dataInicio;
```

E ela mostra assim:

[image: view para mostrar a data]

Eu queria que mostrasse assim:

> 30/09/2016 - Dia/Mês/Ano e sem horários.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque um getter específico na sua entidade:

```java
public String getDataInicioFormatada() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    return sdf.format(this.getDataInicio());
}
```

Daí na sua view você faz isso:

```xml
<p:column headerText="Data de Início" filterBy="#{projeto.dataInicio}">
    <h:outputText value="#{projeto.dataInicioFormatada}"/>
</p:column>
```

Observe que o `filterBy` não é alterado. Apenas o `outputText` é alterado.

Answer (score 1):

Testa com o código abaixo:

```
<p:column headerText="Data de Início" filterBy="#{projeto.dataInicio}">
    <h:outputText value="#{projeto.dataInicio}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
   </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando uma data do tipo `java.util.Date`, da para resolver apenas no `JSF`, utilizando `<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>`.

Exemplo:

```
<h:outputText value="#{lista.dtEmissao}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Usando o seu exemplo:

```
<p:column headerText="Data de Início" filterBy="#{projeto.dataInicio}">
    <h:outputText value="#{projeto.dataInicio}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

O `filterBy` (ou `sortBy`) também não é afetado e ainda entende o campo como data, mas a exibição com o `outputText` será formatada.